# can we install IIS to Windows Mobile 6.1?

Tags: iis, installation, windows-mobile

can we install IIS to Windows Mobile 6.1 ? As I Have develop a web application in >net and I want to use that same application in Windows Mobile 6.1 ,PDA, as offline application. Ya Surely I will implement that one with Sql server CE but to run it I have to host it on PDA. So can we host it there???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer, no, IIS wont run on Windows Mobile.

Long answer (read: alternate solution), your best developing a WinForms (mobile) version using SQL CE.

If you write your code well, place all your business logic within the same assembly, then you can build a regular web interface (asp.net and/or asp.net-mvc) which will implement your business logic, the write the aformentioned WinForms Mobile version, implementing the same class library for business logic.

Comment: so at the end I have to develop mobile version for interface .... and there is no way that I can use that asp.net web version because of IIS absence  ... right

Comment: Yes; however, if your PDAs have internet access, they could access the same web interface as everyone else.